# Upload numerous item to database via csv

Tags: php, sql, laravel, csv, file-upload

I am trying to upload number of students to a database via a csv file. I am able to upload a database to the csv file, however it is only uploading the first student to the database and not the rest. Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Function which uploads the csv file to the database:

```
function csvstudents(Request $req) {
    if ($req->hasFile('csvfile')) {
        $path = $req->file('csvfile')->getRealPath();
        $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();

        if ($data->count()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $arr = [
                    'studentID' => $value->studentID, 
                    'name' => $value->name,
                    'var1' => $value->var1,
                    'var2' => $value->var2,
                    'email' => $value->email,
                    'address1' => $value->address1,
                    'c1' => $value->c1,
                    'c2' => $value->c2,
                    'c3' => $value->c3,
                    'c4' => $value->c4,
                    'c5' => $value->c5,
                    'c6' => $value->c6,
                    'c7' => $value->c7,
                    'c8' => $value->c8,
                    'c9' => $value->c9,
                    'c10' => $value->c10,

                ];

            }
            if (!empty($arr)) {
                DB::table('students')->insert($arr);
                return "Success";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test CSV file:

```
9   Katy Perry  A*  WellDone!   katy@hotmail.com    91 Fromans Road, Moseley, Birmingham, B94TJ 4   4   5   6   7   6   5   4   2   2

10  chut winder A*  WellDone!   katy@hotmail.com    92 Fromans Road, Moseley, Birmingham, B94TJ 4   4   5   6   7   6   5   4   2   2

11  Test        A*  WellDone!   katy@hotmail.com    93 Fromans Road, Moseley, Birmingham, B94TJ 4   4   5   6   7   6   5   4   2   2
```

So f I was to upload the test database it would only insert the first student in to the database only, I want to upload all 3 entries.

Comment: Is there some kind of primary key / unique key on the database? I noticed all three records have the same email address on them

Comment: yes sorry that was only for testing the 1st entry is a student id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either insert inside the loop or push to `$arr` and insert outside the loop

**Inside loop**

```
if ($data->count()) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $arr = ['studentID' => $value->studentID, 
            'name' => $value->name,
            'var1' => $value->var1,
            'var2' => $value->var2,
            ...
        ];

        DB::table('students')->insert($arr);
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

**Outside loop**

```
if ($data->count()) {
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $arr[] = ['studentID' => $value->studentID, 
            'name' => $value->name,
            'var1' => $value->var1,
            'var2' => $value->var2,
            ...
        ];
    }
    if (! empty($arr)) {
        DB::table('students')->insert($arr);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, @chanafdo just tried still only the last entry in the csv file is uploading

Comment: @CrazyDar See the updated answer. move the return outside of loop

Comment: yes still only uploading the first person in the the file to the databsse

Comment: Can you check whether the data count `dd($data->count())` or data `dd($data)` contains more than one record

Comment: can you check the data count as in my previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169359/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-crazy-dar).

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding new values into `$arr`, you're overwriting it on each iteration:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $arr = ['studentID' => $value->studentID,
```

You probably want this:

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $arr[] = ['studentID' => $value->studentID,
```

This assumes that your `insert()` method can take an array. If that's not the case, then you can leave your array as is and just add a call to `insert()` inside the loop.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, but it is still inputting only the last record in to the database @Alex Howansky